# xslt read/print namespace at declaration

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, namespaces, xslt-1.0

I had to transform a xml to a html with xlst. This is fairly simple if you don't consider the namespace declarations.

Because I had some trouble to find this solution for handling the namespaces and **I'm currious if this can be done in a easier way I create this post.**

My Problem was:
*How to print the xmlns when it is declared and not on each node.*

Given the following xml the namespaces should be printed when they are declared. The root element has two namespace declarations but calling

```
namespace::node()
```

All the Namespaces are listed.

```
<foo:root xmlns:foo="http://www.foo.com" xmlns:bar="http://www.bar.com">
    <xx:child xmlns:xx="http://www.xx.com" />
    <bar:otherChild>
        <defaultNamespace />
    </bar:otherChild>
</foo:root>
```

Solution:

```
<!--
Select the current namespace without the xml namespace and without the namespaces of all ancestors (parents)
-->
<xsl:for-each select="namespace::node()[name()!='xml'][not(.=ancestor::*[position()&gt;1]/namespace::*)]">
  <xsl:variable name="name" select="name(current())" /> <!-- would be foo -->
  <xsl:variable name="namespace" select="current()" /> <!-- http://www.foo.com -->
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: Your question is not clear (and neither is your solution).  What is the actual output you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

I think the expression you are looking for is this....

```
<xsl:for-each select="namespace::node()[name()!='xml'][not(. = ../ancestor::*/namespace::node())]">
```

i.e. Write out the namespace if it doesn't already exist on an ancestor of the current node.

Try this XSLT as an example

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

  <xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:text>Node: </xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="local-name()" />
    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:for-each select="namespace::node()[name()!='xml'][not(. = ../ancestor::*/namespace::node())]">
      <xsl:value-of select="name(current())" /> 
      <xsl:text> - </xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="current()" />
      <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates />
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```